# fetching firestore data in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, completionhandler

I'm using firebase firestore and authentication .

My app is basically managing orders, when a user sends a new order to firestore it gets a openOrder default Boolean var, I have another app that manage this order and once my other app reads the order the boolean var changes value.

All of that works.

My issue is when a user closes completly the app and then reopens it I need to check if the openOrder is true or not and according to that set my rootViewController .
I'm using a completion handler to fetch the openOrder var and check if it is true or not but applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns true before I set my local vars according to the firestore functions.

my code is :

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

       let reValue = loadPriviousDishesIfUserQuitsAppBeforeClosingTab(completion: { success in
            guard success! else { return }
            //here I have all the values I need and need to return only here 
        })

    return true
}



   func loadPriviousDishesIfUserQuitsAppBeforeClosingTab(completion: @escaping (Bool?) ->()) {
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    let myUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    db.collection("users").whereField("user", isEqualTo: myUserID!).whereField("openOrder", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
        else {

            for doc in  (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                guard let  restID = doc.data()[ResttId"]
                    else {return}
                myRestaurant.restID = restID as? String
                self.setMyRestMenu(completion: { success in
                    guard success else { return }


                    //here I set all my values using fetching all the data from firestore,

                })
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a loading activity above the rootViewController until get that value , then

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


   let reValue = loadPriviousDishesIfUserQuitsAppBeforeClosingTab(completion: { success in
        guard success! else { return }
        //here I have all the values I need and need to return only here 

         let stor = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let welcomeView = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderView")

        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeView )

        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true

       self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    })

    return true
}
```

Edit : set storyboardID here

[image]

Comment: wouldn't return true will be called before setting the root view controller?

Comment: it will be called anyway when the app opens setted to the rootViewController that you set the entry point to in storyboard , but because of network delay , you have to cover that root with hoverView(That hides it's content whether it's main VC or not) until you get the value and then decide where you want to go whether  to remove the hover or push a new VC that relates to your app logic

Comment: I tried to implement it , I crash on     
` let welcomeView = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderView")
`
I changed the view's storyboard ID to match orderView but I get this error :
`Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x604000474740>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'tabBarViewController''`
any thoughts ?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: select tab bar and add the id to it as attached photo

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)